# java.security.PrivilegedActionException: sun.nio.fs.UnixException on Tomcat starting from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am running a web application using the Spring TC(tomcat-7.0.55) which is on Amazon ec2 instance. I can start the server manually from the ec2 instance and the server is running fine. But when the server is started from the Jenkins build i am getting 
"java.security.PrivilegedActionException: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: No such file or directory" and the server is not starting.

Can anybody help me solve this issue.

Full Stack trace:'

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5499)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
        at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:190)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(SeedGenerator.java:168)
        at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:201)
        at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:221)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:491)
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: No such file or directory
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: No such file or directory
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.getcwd(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(UnixFileSystem.java:67)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.<init>(LinuxFileSystem.java:39)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:46)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:56)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.<init>(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.createProvider(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:48)
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:63)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:108)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just resolved the same issue.

Caused by: sun.nio.fs.UnixException: No such file or directory
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.getcwd(Native Method)

this exception means trying to get current working directory but the directory has gone.

Probably you deleted the directory that tomcat had been started from.